# Expression for assigning ID by grouping and ordering polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, fields-attributes, expression, unique-id

To solve a problem ([details see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378198/categorized-symbology-for-polygons-using-qgis)) I am looking for an expression in QGIS (3.16) that creates a new field and should achieve this:

1. On a polygon layer, it should group together all polygons that have the same attribute-value
2. For each group, it should order the containing features according to some value, let's say for demonstration purposes the area (`$area`)
3. It should assign kind of an auto-increment value to the features of each group (smallest gets 1)

The result would look something like this:

[image]

I tried different combinations of aggregate and arrays, however, I'm not sure where to start and how to combine: how do I create an expression that creates such a new value?

Comment: Also check this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364563/adding-consecutive-unique-id-starting-from-1-for-each-distinct-set-of-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers), which you can then export if you need to persist the values.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query.

```sql
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_field_name order by st_area(geometry)) as newID, *
from myLayer
```

So, it takes all fields (`*`) from `myLayer` and creates a new field `"newID"`.

This ID is the current row ID, that is grouped by `category_field_name` so it restarts at 1 for every group. At last, the rows are ordered by `area` ascending.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRequest

layer = iface.activeLayer()

original_field = "group"

# order by group
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
clause = QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(original_field, ascending=False)
orderby = QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([clause])
request.setOrderBy(orderby)

current_group = None
last_group = None
new_field = "group_id"

if target_field not in layer.fields().names():
    new_field = QgsField(new_field, QVariant.Int)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([new_field])
    layer.updateFields()

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
        current_group = f[field_name]
        if current_group != last_group:
            id = 1
        else:
            id += 1

        last_group = current_group
        f[new_field] = id
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [@GabrielDeLuca's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364575/99589):

```
array_find(
    array_reverse(
        array_agg(
            "id",
            group_by:="Group",
            order_by:="area"
            )
        ),
    "id"
    ) + 1
```

[image: result]

Comment: Great! That is probably the expression I was looking for two years before. As the answer by JGH solved my problem back then, I will leave the accecpted answer.

Comment: Of course, leave the answer attached to @JGH! I love Virtual Layers @_@