# Numbering points that are contained in polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, unique-id, numbering, feature-count

In QGIS 3.16.8-Hannover I have a layer with polygons and I have a layer with points. Each polygon contains a certain number of points, I would like to assign a number to each point in sequential order in the attribute column `"Sequence"`.

*'Polygon A'* - Has 10 points, in this case, I would have point with `"Sequence"` value of 1, then a point `"Sequence"` value of 2, and so on up to 10.

*'Polygon B'* - has 12 points, it would be the same as above just it would go up to 12 instead.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409438/88814

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the `"Sequence"` attribute with this expression using the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator):

```
if(overlay_within('polygon'), -- name of the polygon layer
    array_find(
        array_agg(
            "id", -- id field in the point layer
            group_by:=overlay_within('polygon', "id") -- any field from the polygon layer
            ),
        "id" -- id field in the point layer
        ) + 1,
    NULL)
```

---

**References:**

- [Expression for assigning ID by grouping and ordering polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378266/expression-for-assigning-id-by-grouping-and-ordering-polygons-in-qgis)
- [Adding consecutive unique ID starting from 1 for each distinct set of values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364563/adding-consecutive-unique-id-starting-from-1-for-each-distinct-set-of-values)

Comment: "id", -- id field in the point layer

Can it be fid?

Comment: @Ghostwriter84 yes, of course!